# Create a byte array according to given String In Java

Tags: java

I just need to create a byte array out of the given String.

For example, if my String is `String ss = "21331UA";` then the byte array elements should correspond to them as follows.

```
2 1 3 3 1 U A
```

I could have created it statically as this. `byte[] arr = new byte[]{2,1,3,3,1,'U','A'}` But have to create this byte array in the runtime dyanamically as this changes time to time. Thats the problem.

I just tried as follows and print them, it contains their corresponding ASCII values.**This is not what I want.**

```
byte[] arr = ss.getBytes();

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
}
Ans==> 50  49  51  51  49  85  65
```

Really appreciate any guidance.... Thanks in advance

Comment: byte is a **numeric** type in java, do you mean **char** '2', '1', '3' ...?

Comment: Hi Mana, I just need to dyanamically create this byte array to proceed to next step. Thats the problem. Otherwise I could have created it with this syntax... byte[] arr = new byte[]{2,1,3,3,1,'U','A'}. Thats why I am looking to create this array dyanamically in the run time and to use it in my application. Thanks...

Comment: @JibW If you were to print out the byte[] the way you create it, you'll get the exact same ASCII (which are the byte values) of that array. Calling `getBytes()` is the correct dynamic way of getting those values.

Comment: Hi Poindexter, My requirement is to create the byte array and to use it in the application. Since when I created with the getBytes() way it didn't work properly, I printed them and check what's going wrong there. My requirement is to create the byte array... Thanks

Comment: Ya, but like I said earlier, byte is **numeric**. It can only hold numbers from -128 to 127. **It can not hold an 'U' but the byte representation for 'U' wich is 85**. The _ss.getBytes();_ call is absolutely correct and does the right thing: Get the Byte representation of your String!

Answer (score 6):

You could cast the values in your byte array like this:

```
System.out.print((char)arr[i] + "  ");
```

Or, alternatively, set your byte array to chars right off the bat:

```
char[] arr = ss.toCharArray();

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Yes When I print like this it prints what I want. I just need to create the byte array which exactly containing the characters of the String. Not ASCII Values...Because I just need a byte array that contains the exact characters I suggest by the string. Thanks

Comment: @JibW  your code `ss.getBytes()` does exactly that, it is the `byte[]` representation of your String.

Comment: Hi cklab, Ya Thats the problem. I just need a way to create a byte array of the characters of the String...

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just need to dyanamically create this byte array to proceed to next step. Thats the problem. Otherwise I could have created it with this syntax... byte[] arr = new byte[]{2,1,3,3,1,'U','A'}. Thats why I am looking to create this array dyanamically in the run time and to use it in my application. A char array is not going to work for my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @JibW, a byte array and a char array are essentially the same thing in that they are storing the exact same data. What you hope to pull back from these arrays is a matter of interpretation. If you want to store the string's individual characters in a byte array, you must cast the values you index as chars, otherwise you will see numeric data when you print to screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to CAST `byte` to `char` as type of array `arr[i]` is `byte`.

Simply say

```
System.out.print((char) arr[i] + "  ");
```

Comment: Hi Fahim, When printing of course I can cast it like this. But I am looking for a way to create a byte array with the exact characters that the string contains.